# How to change Sharepoint server response language?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest, language

I'm using an existing SharePoint 2013 Server that was installed in French.
I'm testing different features of the SharePoint REST API and as you would expect I'm getting a LOT of exceptions and errors.

The problem is when you Google an exception in a language other than English you don't get a lot of results.

Is there a way to change SharePoint's settings so it sends English responses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change the language of the ULS logs / response, it is same language as your SharePoint default installation. In your case it will be French.

Even you install the English Language pack, it will not change the ULS logs language.

couple of options.

1. Just use a translator ( google or bing) and translate your error in English then search for it.
2. or install the SharePoint in English version then install the French Language pack.A lot of work, which i dont think you want to do.
3. required extra effort, if you have lower environment( dev) then install the English language pack their. Now setup the same site collection(french) in English language and run your Rest code their.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Waqas, I think I'll continue with option (1) even though Google translate doesn't give 100% accurate translations especially with a lot of technical terms, and Bing is worst.